# ¿Cómo redireccionar la información del rastreador gps externo a mi bd en firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, gps

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación en Android usando Firebase, deseo poder conectar un GPS externo para poder realizar el rastreo del vehículo por medio de la APP, compré un GPS por internet pero encuentro como realizar el direccionamiento la información a mi BD en Firebase, quería saber si alguien tiene algún modelo de GPS que sea fácil de configurar y que recomendaciones me darían para poder realizar la conexión y que es lo que necesito, Agradezco sus respuestas.

Comment: Hola Alexis, Las recomendaciones no son validas en este sitio. Ademas tu pregunta es muy amplia. Has de investigar e intentar hacerlo. Si durante el desarrollo de la app tienes dudas concretas debidos a fallos o problemas, pregunta aqui siguiendo la guia [ask]. Un saludo

Comment: cual es el problema? obteniendo la ubicacion? subiendo los datos a firebase?

Comment: el problema es en obtener los datos del gps externo, como poder hacerlo y enviarlo a mi bd en firebase, soy nuevo en todo esto, agradezco de antemano sus comentarios.